# Change File Split size in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I have a bunch of small files in an HDFS directory. Although the volume of the files is relatively small, **the amount of processing time per file is huge**. That is, a `64mb` file, which is the default split size for `TextInputFormat`,  would take even several hours to be processed.

What I need to do, is to **reduce the split size**, so that I can **utilize even more nodes** for a job.

So the question is, how is it possible to split the files by let's say `10kb`? Do I need to implement my own `InputFormat` and `RecordReader` for this, or is there any parameter to set? Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The parameter **`mapred.max.split.size`** which can be set per job individually is what you looking for. Don't change **`dfs.block.size`** because this is global for HDFS and can lead to problems.

Comment: dfs.block.size isn't necessarily global; you can set specific files to have a different block size than the default for your filesystem. I agree that mapred.max.split.size is probably the way to go in this case, though.

Comment: [`mapred.max.split.size` is deprecated. The new property name is `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html). I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188315/behavior-of-the-parameter-mapred-min-split-size-in-hdfs) very helpful for tuning input split sizes.

Answer (score 23):

Hadoop the Definitive Guide, page 203 "The maximum split size defaults to the maximum value that can be represented by a Java long type. It has an effect only when it is less than the block size, **forcing splits to be smaller than a block**. 
The split size is calculated by the formula:

```
max(minimumSize, min(maximumSize, blockSize))
```

by default

```
minimumSize < blockSize < maximumSize
```

so the split size is `blockSize`

For example,

```
Minimum Split Size 1
Maximum Split Size 32mb
Block Size  64mb
Split Size  32mb
```

Hadoop Works better with a small number of large files than a large number of small files. One reason for this is that FileInputFormat generates splits in such a way that each split is all or part of a single file. If the file is very small ("small" means significantly smaller than an HDFS block) and there are a lot of them, then each map task will process very little input, and there will be a lot of them (one per file), each of which imposes extra bookkeeping overhead. Compare a 1gb file broken into sixteen 64mb blocks, and 10.000 or so 100kb files. The 10.000 files use one map each, and the job time can be tens or hundreds of times slower than the equivalent one with a single input file and 16 map tasks.

---

Answer (score 3):

Here is fragment which illustrates correct way to do what is needed here without magic configuration strings. Needed constant is defined inside `FileInputFormat`. Block size can be taken if needed from default HDFS block constant but it has pretty good probability to be user defined.

Here I just divide maximum split size by 2 if it was defined.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

// ....

final long DEFAULT_SPLIT_SIZE = 128 * 1024 * 1024;
final Configuration conf = ...

// We need to lower input block size by factor of two.
conf.setLong(
    FileInputFormat.SPLIT_MAXSIZE,
    conf.getLong(
        FileInputFormat.SPLIT_MAXSIZE, DEFAULT_SPLIT_SIZE) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom input format which extends combinefileinputformat[has its own pros nad cons base don the hadoop distribution]. which combines the input splits into the value specified in mapred.max.split.size