# Filtering an InputStream on-the-fly

Tags: java

Data coming in from the Input stream consists of Multiple JSON objects on each line. I'm only interested in a small (5-8%) of the objects (hence lines) coming in from the stream, those which contain a particular JSON key-value combination.

I'm reading data from the InputStream and writing it to a file. Is it possible to write only those objects (i.e. lines) which match a particular simple Regex? 
(Since the object is huge, parsing it as a json and looking for the key would be a waste of time, a Regex match would be far quicker.)

This is just a wild idea, I'm not sure if this is possible at all. If it is, any tips, links, pointers?

The total data coming in is ~3TB from various different InputStreams on 40 separate hosts in EMR. Because of various reasons (mainly those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862340/reducing-number-of-map-tasks-during-hadoop-streaming)), I want to avoid post-processing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `BufferedReader` on an `InputStreamReader`. Then you would `readLine()` and match that particular line to the pattern. If it matches, write it to the file. Make sure that your reader has the correct character encoding.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new File(...)))

String line;
while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
    if (line.matches(patternString)) {
        writer.println(line);
    }
}
```

Using a `BufferedReader` is significantly faster than a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which can scan an InputStream.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourInputStream);

scanner.findWithinHorizon("your_pattern", 0);
```

Be mindful that:

- `findWithinHorizon` can cause large amounts of data to be buffered if the matches are sparse. So you maybe want to filter by a smaller match first, like a maximum length.
- Regex is not elegant at analyzing nested patterns like `{{}}` such as a Json allows. So design your pattern accordingly.