# How does spark determine the number of tasks?

Tags: apache-spark, task, apache-spark-dataset

I am a bit confused by the number of tasks that are created by Spark when reading a number of text files.

Here is the code:

```
val files = List["path/to/files/a/23", 
                 "path/to/files/b/", 
                 "path/to/files/c/0"]
val ds = spark.sqlContext.read.textFile(files :_*)
ds.count()
```

Each of the folders `a, b, c` contains 24 files, so that there are a total of 26 files since the complete `b` folder is read. Now if I execute an action, like `.count()`, the Spark UI shows me that there are 24 tasks. However, I would have thought that there are 26 tasks, as in 1 task per partition and 1 partition for each file.

It would be great if someone could give me some more insights into what is actually happening.

Comment: What is the total number of cores you are using for the job? And have you set any configurations?

Comment: To make it easy to understand. Can you post your code and your spark ui details.

Comment: @SimonSchiff I used 8 cores and I have nothing configure that I know of. However, that seems to be the correct direction. I tried executing the code on a bigger machine and it had the expected 26 tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Text files are loaded using Hadoop formats. Number of partitions depends on:

- `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize`
- `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`
- `minPartitions` argument if provided
- block size
- compression if present (splitable / not-splitable).

You'll find example computations here: [Behavior of the parameter "mapred.min.split.size" in HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19188315)