# How to split ORC file based on size?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, orc, apache-crunch

I have a requirement where I want to split 5GB ORC file into 5 files with 1 GB size each.
ORC file is splittable. Does that mean we can only split file stripe by stripe ?
but I have requirement where I want to split orc file based on size. 
for ex.split 5GB ORC file into 5 files with 1 GB size each.
if possible please share example.

Answer (score 3):

A common approach and considering that you file size can be 5GB, 100GB, 1TB, 100TB, etc. You might want to mount a Hive table pointing to this file and define one more table pointing to a different directory, then run an insert from one table to the other using [insert](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries) statement provided by Hive.

At the beginning of the script, make sure you have the following Hive flags:

```
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=1073741824;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=1073741824;
```

In this way, the output average for each reducer will be `1073741824 Bytes` which is equal to `1GB`.

If you want to use only Java code, play with these flags:

```
mapred.max.split.size
mapred.min.split.size
```

Please check these, they are very useful:

- [split size vs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549261/split-size-vs-block-size-in-hadoop)
- [min split size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188315/behavior-of-the-parameter-mapred-min-split-size-in-hdfs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is there any way I can do splitting using core java only not hive ?

Comment: I need a solution which is entirely based on Core java api. Not hadoop or mapreduce. Anyways thank you very much for taking time to respond'

Comment: @ShamDesale remove the tags from the question then. Remove hadoop, apache-crunch and apache given that the question has nothing to do with hadoop.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question - I am reading ORC file in java and then split this file based on size. for instance if file size is 5GB then I need to create 5 files with 1GB size each. I am able to do this using java. only problem here is that original files stripe size is different and split file stripe size is different. I want to set original files stripe size to all split files. How I can retrieve stripe size of file using orcreader in java ? Please reply