# How and where is input split size mentioned or passed to a MR program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, input-split, bigdata

I understand  what input split size and what a block size means. But what I am trying to understand is where and how the input split size is mentioned for a MR program... is it passed a parameter while starting a MR job using (Hadoop jar MRPROGRAM ... etc) or is it specified in the MR Job configuration program or is it mentioned some where else. Please explain.

Comment: have a look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678180/change-file-split-size-in-hadoop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change File Split size in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678180/change-file-split-size-in-hadoop)